# PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of -1 seconds exceeded

Tags: php-fpm, timeout

I have a script which has a long running MySQL query and PHP returns a huge number of records as it is used to fetch raw logs for users.

I am finding it a little strange but i am getting time out after setting max_execution_time = -1.

I have also set max_input_time = -1 and memory_limit = -1 to make it work atleast for testing server.

Server has php5-fpm. Have also done multiple restarts with `service php5-fpm` restart.

What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

You should use "0" and not "-1".

REF:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776400/make-script-execution-to-unlimited

Comment: Can you explain this a bit better?  Maybe provide a reference to the docs?

Comment: Quick search in the docs would show this. I don't know where the -1 came from.